# Linux Shell Script * or ???? is replace automatically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have some files stored on a server. I have to get all those files using a pattern and exclude the file which contains the current date as the file name.
Files are given below

```
/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2022-05-11.log
/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2022-05-13.log
/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2022-05-14.log
/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2022-05-16.log
/var/tomcat/logs/error_1.log
/var/tomcat/logs/error_2.log
/var/tomcat/logs/error_3.log
/var/tomcat/logs/error_4.log
```

For this, I have stored patterns in a file and I want to read the pattern of that file and find all files with the help of those patterns.
Pattern Input File content is given below, in below I have used '%Y-%m-%d' to identify the date format so that I can exclude the current date file.

```
/var/tomcat/logs/catalina.*.log;%Y-%m-%d
/var/tomcat/logs/error_*.log
```

I have developed a shell script which is given below

```
#!/bin/sh

pattern_filepath=$1
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    pattern_var="$line"
    echo pattern: "$pattern_var"
    filepath=""
    date_format=""

    if [[ $pattern_var == *";"* ]];
    then
        echo "Semicolons ; separator is there"
        filepath=($(echo "$pattern_var" | cut -f1 -d ';'))
        echo filepath: "$filepath"
        date_format=($(echo "$pattern_var" | cut -f2 -d ';'))
    else
        echo "Semicolons ; separator is not there"
        filepath=$pattern_var
    fi

    echo "date_format: "$date_format
done < "$pattern_filepath"
```

Command to run the script

```
sh /var/monitoring/test.sh "/var/monitoring/pattern" > /var/monitoring/test.log
```

Inside the log file, I can see, that in the file path variable I am getting the value as a date but that should be with an asterisk instead of a date.
Log file 'test.log'

```
pattern: /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.*.log;%Y-%m-%d
Semicolons ; separator is there
filepath: /var/tomcat/logs/catalina.2022-05-11.log
date_format: %Y-%m-%d
pattern: /var/tomcat/logs/error_*.log
Semicolons ; separator is not there
date_format:
```

Please help me with this, how can I achieve this?

Comment: It's easy to write specification, not easy to write implementation. Start with implementation, not specification. `but that should be with an asterisk instead of a date` No, The `$(...)` is unquoted, it is subject to filename expansion, so you are printing the first `filepath` array element. `how can I achieve this?` I do not know what answer do you expect, you have to actually write the code to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, straight to the point.  Achieves the requirement, without the complexity of patterns, or lists, or ...

```
#!/bin/bash

sourcedir="/var/tomcat/logs"
if [[ ! -d "$sourcedir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: source directory $sourcedir does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
targetdir="/tmp/somedir"
if [[ ! -d "$targetdir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: target directory $targetdir does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Get the catalina logs
cp "$sourcedir"/catalina.*.log "$targetdir"

# Remove the catalina log for today
filetoremove="$targetdir"/catalina.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
if [[ -f "$filetoremove" ]]
then
    rm -f "$filetoremove"
fi

# Get the error logs
cp "$sourcedir"/error_*.log "$targetdir"
```

You can add error checking and recovery for the `cp` and `rm` commands.